# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'price' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

'this is my controller' 'i need help when i am click object  i am want take row data from phpmyadmin  thank you everyone  '

public function store(Request $request){

```
    $this->middleware('auth');


    $tours = new tour();

    $tours->name=$request->input('name');
    $tours->date=$request->input('date');
    $tours->price=$request->input('price');
    $tours->hotel=$request->input('hotel');
    $tours->created_at=$request->input('created_at');
    $tours->service=$request->input('service');
    $tours->some=$request->input('some');


    if($request->hasFile('picture')){
        $file=$request->file('picture');
        $extension =$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename =time() .'.'.$extension;
        $file->move(public_path('images'),$filename);
        $tours->picture=$filename;

    }

    $tours->save();
    return redirect('admin/tour');       
}
```

'this is my view'

```
                    <div class="bc" style=" border-radius: 4px; width: 70%; height:45rem;">
                            <h4 style="text-align: center; position: relative; top:15px;">Tur Haqqında Məlumat</h4>
                            <strong style=" position: relative; top:15px;">Qiymət</strong>
                            <p style=" position: relative; top:15px;  width: 100%; font-weight: 400; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" name='price'>{{$tour->price}} AZN</p>
                            <hr/>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, try to describe what you are trying to achieve, and what happens?

Comment: The error is in `{{ $tour->price }}`. `$tour` object must be null. Try `dd($tour)` and check if its null. For variables to work in views, you need to pass them from the controller. In this case, you need to pass the `$tour` to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$tours` to your view:

```
return redirect('admin/tour', ['tour'=> $tours]);
```

On a side note, I would use `$tour` instead of the plural version `$tours` that you are using now in your controller.